# Is there a way to update and display x y next to mouse pointer in jfreechart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I would like to display the (x, y) location of the mouse pointer with respect the coordinate system of the current jfree chart. I would like to do this constantly even if the mouse pointer is not set on any part of the graph.

I know I can activate the tooltip the way explained  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087680/jfreechart-get-mouse-co-ordinates) but that displays the mouse location only if the mouse is on top of a graph point. How can I see the XYs all the time next to mouse pointer (tooltip or something)?

Answer (score 2):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20081801/230513), the coordinates are in the `MouseEvent` returned by `getTrigger()` in the `ChartMouseEvent` sent to a `ChartMouseListener`.